# Pandas utilize Numpy Vectorization in a user defined function instead of using loops/lambda.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[image: ytho]

Objective: For every cell in Vendor: I want to check if EVERY word in the vendor's name exists in the Names Database. i.e. Adam AND Smith must BOTH exist to make IsPerson = TRUE

I know that I can do this using lambda.apply() and other ways but all of them are loops based. I'd like to make this as fast and as efficient as possible because I have 1.2 million rows. I've heard about Numpy Vectorization but not sure how to use it when I need to run some routine on the individual contents of each cell. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately if working with strings in numpy/pandas always are loops under the hoods.

Idea is create `DataFrame` from split by whitespaces, forward filling last values, filter by `isin` and last test if all `True`s per rows:

```
df1['IsPerson'] = (df1['Vendor'].str.split(expand=True)
                                .ffill(axis=1)
                                .isin(df2['Persons'].tolist())
                                .all(axis=1))
```

Solution with sets:

```
s = set(df2['Persons'])
df1['IsPerson'] = ~df1['Vendor'].map(lambda x: s.isdisjoint(x.split()))
```

**Performance**

Depends of length of Both DataFrames, number of unique values and number of matched values. So in real data should be different.

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 100000
L = list('abcdefghijklmno ')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Vendor': [''.join(x) for x in np.random.choice(L, (N, 5))]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Persons': [''.join(x) for x in np.random.choice(L, (N * 10, 5))]})
```

---

```
In [133]: %%timeit
     ...: s = set(df2['Persons'])
     ...: df1['IsPerson1'] = ~df1['Vendor'].map(lambda x: s.isdisjoint(x.split()))
     ...: 
470 ms ± 7.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [134]: %%timeit
     ...: df1['IsPerson2'] = (df1['Vendor'].str.split(expand=True)
     ...:                                 .ffill(axis=1)
     ...:                                 .isin(df2['Persons'].tolist())
     ...:                                 .all(axis=1))
     ...:                                 
858 ms ± 18.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Watch out new column name typos

Comment: Wow! That's very clever & very creative technique. Interestingly enough I've tired all of your 3 methods on 100,000 rows. The one you've deleted in your edit yesterday is actually the fastest!

%timeit df['IsPerson'] = (df['CleanName'].str.split(expand=True).isin(PersonsDB['NAME'].tolist()+ [None]).all(axis=1))
#Took 4.27 seconds

the ffill one took 5.10 seconds and the isdisjoint took 9.75 seconds

Great stuff. Thanks!